# While selecting image from imagePicker, app gets crashes for iOS11.2.6, Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have one imageView and I want to select image from Camera/Gallery to keep selected image on imageView. But, on selection of Gallery, my app gets crashing in iOS 11.2.6 with given error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only RGBA or White color
>   spaces are supported in this situation.'

But, it is working fine for iOS version less than 11. I have added all the required things in info.plist. Still it is not working for iOS 11.

Please help me out in this.

**Updated:**
My Code

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"Choose From" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        // Cancel button tappped.
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        }];
    }]];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Gallery" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        UIImagePickerController *imgpicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgpicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        imgpicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imgpicker.delegate=(id)self;
        [self presentViewController:imgpicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }]];

[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**I am using the same code for another project, so it working for another project. But for this project it is crashing.**

Comment: post some code. show what you have tried so far

Comment: @Vinodh:My question is updated, you can check it out.

Comment: I think u forgot this line         [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: yup it is there, before I forgot to keep in question code. Now I have updated my code again.

Comment: maybe you are using some third party library in this project, which causes the crush

Comment: or setting an appearance for the navigation bar or image picker somewhere in the code

Comment: @AndreyVolobuev: I am using following pods
pod 'HCSStarRatingView', '~> 1.5'
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
pod 'SWTableViewCell', '~> 0.3.7
pod 'UITextView+PlaceholderExt'

Comment: you may get  this issue if your using colorWithPatternImage with UITabBar or UINavigationBar

Comment: Yes I am using tabBarViewController in this project and using clear color for Tabbar

Comment: @RajeshDharani: Thank you so much, I have found the crash now. Due to tabBarViewController clear color, it is crashing. 
Once again thanks allot.

Comment: @SagarSukode your always welcome ji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just because of UITabbar remove background image for Tabbar.

It works fine for me.